# PKIX path building failed on Kubernetes AutoDevOps

Tags: java, maven, kubernetes, gitlab-ci

I'm using a custom [artifacotry repository](https://jfrog.com/open-source/) on which I deploy my projects. 
This is working fine when I'm working on my local machine but I've enable the AutoDevOps feature of Gitlab and integrate my project with a Kubernetes cluster.

The kubernetes cluster is managed by [rancher](https://rancher.com/).

The issue is that the build runned on Gitlab is failing with the following error:

> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of
>   its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: Could not
>   transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to
>   adibox-snapshots
>   (https://artifactory.mydomain.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot): Transfer
>   failed for
>   https://artifactory.mydomain.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom:
>   PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

If it was running on a local machine I know I could add the certificate to the java keystore by using `keytool` command lines. But I do not find where, in case of the AutoDevOps I could add the certificate. My best guess would be to add it on the Runner machine but I do not have any control on it as it's managed by Gitlab.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding

```
before_script:
  - keytool -importcert -file artifactory.cer -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

It will add the certificate to the Gitlab-Runner.